# PHP: How to check more then one row for check a checkbox

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I would like to check a checkbox if I have integer 1 stored in row a or b.

For now I created a working version to check for row 'a'.
How can I check also for row 'b'? So as said above **if row a or/and b has integer 1 stored check the checkbox.**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" value="1" <?php if($row['a'] == "1") { echo "checked"; }?>>
```

Comment: can you use javascript? Your code doesn't really make any sense.  Php is server side.  The input html would be client side. Generally you would check client side inputs with javascript.  Alternatively, when you submit the form you could check either $_GET or $_POST to see what was inputted and then echo out a result

Comment: @DCR Checkboxes get checked server side often.   e.g. Point of Sale some oiptions are pre-checked.  When you review and edit an order.   You review your order and  you find an option checked you did not want. Bring up the edit window with the checkboxes checked as ordered.  Or a editing a multi-tab survey.  Radio buttons, same thing.  No cheese, cheese, extra cheese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. this will echo checked to make the checkbox checked if any of the row contains integer 1

```
<?php ($row['a'] == 1 || $row['b'] == 1) ? 'checked':''; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer works great. Honestly appreciate it :) If someone could please upvote my question. Because DCR didn't understood its downgraded :/ - that would be nice.

Comment: @Jessy642 glad I was able to assist.

Answer (score 1):

```
$checked = array('','checked');

$row['a'] = 1;
$row['b'] = 0;

echo 'Row A<input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" value="1"' . $checked[$row['a']] . ' /><br>';
echo 'Row B<input type="checkbox" name="b" id="b" value="1"' . $checked[$row['b']] . ' /><br>';
echo 'Row A or B<input type="checkbox" name="ab" id="ab" value="1"' . $checked[$row['a'] | $row['b']]   . ' />';
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you also for your comment and help :) For me Ahmd comment worked, that was what I was searching for.

Comment: The reason I posted is because it's a pet peeve of mine.  I loathe code that switches between PHP mode and HTML mode.  I strongly believe there should on be one `<?php` one the first like of the script and one `?>` on the last like.   There is a fair amount of CPU overheard associated with the switching.  I also avoid IF statements whenever possible and I avoid associative arrays and objects.  It's all about efficiency.  I consider a page load time of 0.5 seconds and a GTmetrix score below 99% to be unacceptable.

Comment: Ok wow, that's actually a good point. I am always open for new ideas. Thank you for sharing your idea also. Will give you an upvote too :)